Getting committed text from Windows IME requires Enter press in JavaFX
I want to provide possibility to enter Chinese characters in JavaFX in Windows. This is my test code for TextArea:
public class Foo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        var textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setOnInputMethodTextChanged(e -> {
            System.out.println("Event:" + e.getCommitted().length());
            textArea.appendText(e.getCommitted());
        });
        VBox.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
        var root = new VBox(textArea);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

And this is the result:

How it works:

User starts entering characters.
Windows IME appears.
User selects required symbol, for example, by pressing "2".
IME disappears.
Nothing happens until user presses Enter.
Selected symbol is added.

I don't know Chinese but I tried IME with Firefox and it works without #5. Could anyone say how to do it without making user press Enter for every symbol?
